# Encoded mp4 video won't play in Firefox v33

Tags: command-line, firefox, video, ffmpeg

When this video is encoded with the following ffmpeg command, it cannot be played in Firefox v33 (a blank screen appears). But when I play it in the native VLC player, it works. So here the long ffmpeg command:

```
$ ffmpeg -r 15 -f image2 -i /home/(...)/frames/%d.jpg -i
  /home/(...)/preview.wav -y -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k 
  -vcodec libx264 -b:v 386k -preset ultrafast -profile:v baseline 
  -crf 6 -pix_fmt yuv420p -loglevel warning -movflags faststart 
  /home/(...)/preview.mp4
```

As you can see, preview.mp4 is encoded by a sequence of jpg images with a given wav file.

The ffmpeg output is just this

```
[wav @ 0x35ff460] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : mono
[swscaler @ 0x35f0d80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

Any clues why it won't play on Firefox (and what the other ffpmeg warnings mean)?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please remove `-loglevel warning` and provide the complete console output if possible.

Comment: I notice you're setting both CRF and bit rate. This is mutually exclusive; you either want CRF *or* bitrate.

Comment: Oh right, have removed the bitrate. And here is the complete console output: https://gist.github.com/binarykitchen/0ede2304e89db8091804